# Homebrew broken installation QUALITY STANDARDS

Tags: homebrew

Was trying to install Homebrew on new mac, clicked on the wrong link here https://github.com/Homebrew/install, the one which sets the 2 exports HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE and HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE, so I accidentaly set both of these to '...'. Is there a way to unset them, or is homebrew forever broken for me?

PS: StackOverflow didn't like the title for some unexplained reason, so I added the 'quality standards' in caps, thats somehow fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE` `unset HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE` resets those

environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by formating the mac to factory settings & getting macincloud account. Don't buy crApple products unless you hate yourself